# Total disconnectedness of $\{1/n\}$ with two origins

Tags: general-topology, connectedness

Let $X=\{\frac{1}{n}:n\in\mathbb{N}\}\cup\{0,0'\}$ where we have 'two' origins $0$ and $0'$. (So the topology consists of the usual euclidean plus opens of $0$ where $0'$ replaces $0$.)

> Prove that $X$ is totally disconnected.

Strategy:
Suppose $Y\subset X$ has more then one elements, prove that it is not connected.
There are three cases:
1. $0,0'\notin Y$
2. $0\in Y$, $0'\notin Y$ (or viceversa)
3. $0,0'\in Y$

For 1. we can say: since $\{1/n\}$ is open in $Y$, we easily find multiple clopens in $Y$.
For 2. we can find that $Y$ is a union of $\{0\}$ and some subset of $\{1/n:n\in\mathbb{N}\}$ and for one $n$ the set $\{1/n\}$ is clopen.

How do I prove the case 3.?

Comment: "For example if $Y=\{0\}\cup\{1/n\}$, I dont think we have any clopens here" $\{1/n\}$ is clopen.

Comment: @Arthur But $\{0\}$ is not open in $X$ or is it?

Comment: @Arthur Oh but $\{0\}$ is open in $Y$ of course

Comment: $\{0\}$ might be open, it might not. That depends on how many elements of the form $1/n$ are in $Y$. However, every single $\{1/n\}$ is clopen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For case $3$, you have to split into two cases again:

- There is an element of the form $\frac1n$ in $Y$. In that case, $\{1/n\}$ is a non-empty, proper, clopen subset of $Y$, so $Y$ is not connected.
- $Y = \{0, 0'\}$. In this case, $\{0\}$ is clopen in $Y$, since $\{0\}$ is closed in $X$, and $X\setminus \{0'\}$ is open in $X$, and both of these give $\{0\}$ when intersected with $Y$.